# Syntax error, but correct syntax? unexpected ':', expecting ')'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I have a nested form (see below)

Model Artist (artist is a user)

```
has_many :art_works
  has_many :canvases
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :art_works //artworks is what im currently working on
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :canvases
```

Controller art_works

```
    def new
    @artist = Artist.find(params[:artist_id])
    @artwork = @artist.art_works.build
    respond_to do |format|
          format.html # new.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @artwork }
        end
      end
  def create
    @artwork = ArtWork.new(params[:artwork])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @artwork.save
        format.html { redirect_to @artwork, notice: 'artwork was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @artwork, status: :created, location: @artwork }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @artwork.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

artworks views _form

```
<%= form_for(@artwork, :url => artist_art_works_path(current_artist) :multipart => true) do |f| %>
<p>
    <%= f.file_field :art %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.submit %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

I was pretty positive that this would work, but i'm assuming my :url is incorrect? I'm not really sure what else it would be though. below are my routes for artworks the reason why I am nesting these things is because an artist can upload art into an artwork model the idea is to have several pieces of art in one artwork (like an album has many images inside of it)

```
artist_art_works GET    /artists/:artist_id/art_works(.:format)                          art_works#index
                              POST   /artists/:artist_id/art_works(.:format)                          art_works#create
          new_artist_art_work GET    /artists/:artist_id/art_works/new(.:format)                      art_works#new
         edit_artist_art_work GET    /artists/:artist_id/art_works/:id/edit(.:format)                 art_works#edit
              artist_art_work GET    /artists/:artist_id/art_works/:id(.:format)                      art_works#show
                              PUT    /artists/:artist_id/art_works/:id(.:format)                      art_works#update
                              DELETE /artists/:artist_id/art_works/:id(.:format)                      art_works#destroy
```

Thank you very much in advance for your help. (sorry for the noobness)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a comma. Yeah the error message isn't that helpful.

```
@artwork, :url => artist_art_works_path(current_artist) :multipart => true
```

vs

```
@artwork, :url => artist_art_works_path(current_artist), :multipart => true
```

Comment: omg thank you so much I've literally been staring at this ALL DAY